# What is difference between grep -isn "String\.format" -R . and grep -isn String\.format -R .?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

What is difference between

```
grep -isn "String\.format" -R .
```

and

```
grep -isn String\.format -R .
```

When I use the latter, the results include `String format` and `String.format`, but if I use the former, the results only include `String.format`. This result is same as using

```
grep -isn 'String\.format' -R .
```

Can anyone give an explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without quotation marks, the *shell* interprets `\.` as a `.` before passing the string to `grep`. So `grep` now has a regular expression wildcard and can thus find any character, including a space.

When you included quotation marks, the *shell* passed the full `\.` to `grep`. Now `grep` knows that it must search for a period, and not a wildcard.

Comment: Why the bash shell treats \ specially? How it process the "" and ''?

Comment: @VictorS The backslash is an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Bourne_shell).

Comment: @VictorS: You handle `"` by single-quoting it, e.g. `'"` (escaping also works), you handle `'` by escaping it, e.g. `\'`, or by enclosing it in double-quotes `"'"`; I recommend enclosing any 'suspect' characters in single-quotes and simply escaping unquoted single-quote characters when you want them literally. That's a good intersection of straightforward and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Your shell eats the backslash, so you have to escape it to pass it to `grep`.